# Browser automatically encodes images to base64

Tags: html, browser

I am testing a website and found out that the images are being converted to base64 on the fly. For example, I have a img tag like these

```
<img src="images/ads1.png"/>
```

Accessing the image directly using http://example.com/images/ads1.png will display the image. But on accessing the website, the images are being encoded to base64 like these

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAACklEQVR4nGMAAQAABQABDQottAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

This is what happens when accessing the website in Chrome v26+ and Firefox v18+. Internet Explorer 9 and 10 displays the image correctly.

Comment: I am also facing this problem. I want to crawl an image from a website. While I crawl using it with curl, I am getting proper Image URL when finding in whole page HTML as received but when I extract the image using SimpleHTMLDOM, the image is getting converted to base64 image/jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a javascript plugin changing them on page load. 
There isn't enough information to go on.

Comment: I am also facing this problem. I want to crawl an image from a website. While I crawl using it with curl, I am getting proper Image URL when finding in whole page HTML as received but when I extract the image using SimpleHTMLDOM, the image is getting converted to base64 image/jpeg.